# Cannot use null as map key when trying to map values after groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I'm trying to achieve here is to groupBy all the elements from a Dataframe and then aggregating all their multiple values in a single Column which will contain a `list(map())` of values.

```
val sampleDF = baseDF
  .groupBy(
    Yyyy,
    MmDd,
    SampleField)
  .agg(
    functions.collect_list(
      functions.map(
        Selectors.selectColumn(Name),
        Selectors.selectColumn(Surname)
      )
    )
  )
```

However, when trying to execute that code, the following error is shown.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot use null as map key!`

Why would it matter for a value to be null or not? How is it pretending to use it as the key?

A brief example of what I would like to obtain is...

`2019, 0101, "sampleField", List(Map(name -> Sample, surname -> Sample), Map(name -> Sample2, surname -> Sample2))`

My understanding is that it takes the Column name as key (that will never be null) and then apply the value no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs of `map`:

> Creates a new map column. The input columns must be grouped as
>   key-value pairs, e.g. (key1, value1, key2, value2, ...). The key
>   columns must all have the same data type, and can't be null. The value
>   columns must all have the same data type.

So change your code to something like:

```
val sampleDF = baseDF
.groupBy(
   Yyyy,
   MmDd,
   SampleField)
.agg(
    functions.collect_list(
      functions.map(
        lit("Name"),
        $"Name",
        lit("Surname"),
        $"Surname"
      )
    )
  )
```